# Running script on startup

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to run a script on startup. Script contents are:

```
#!/bin/bash
#this script changes trackpoint settings on startup
echo 'start script'
xinput set-prop 'TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint' 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' {0,1}
xinput set-prop 'TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint' 'libinput Accel Speed' 0.5
```

which changes the sensitivity of trackpoint. The thing is that running command

```
xinput set-prop 'TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint' 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' {0,1}
```

works fine, but when I run my sh script it gives me an error

```
Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
```

I assume that error is in this curvy bracers **{}** but what does it mean and how to fix it?

I run the script with:

```
sh scriptname.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s a `bash` script, you need to use `bash` to start it:

```
bash scriptname.sh
```

However, you don’t really need the brace expansion, so you can also just change the line to:

```
xinput set-prop 'TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint' 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 0 1
```

This way it doesn’t matter whether it’s run with `bash` or `sh`.